# Why are all my classification accuracy scores the same?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm running several machine learning models to find the one which the highest accuracy score, however, all the accuracy scores are the exact same. I performed NLP on social media text and I'm training my models to tag sentiment based on sentiment determined from NLTK.

I'm using the same training and test sets, but I've done this method before in the past and received different scores on different models. Why are all of mine the same? Am I overfitting perhaps?

Here is my code where I'm splitting and training:

```
submissions_sentiment = submissions_df[["Clean_Body", "Clean_Title", "sentiment_label"]]
dataset = submissions_sentiment

X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1]
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values

X_arr = []
for index, row in X.iterrows():
    X_arr.append(row.values)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_arr, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

def identity_tokenizer(text):
    return text

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=identity_tokenizer, lowercase=False)

# fit AND transform the model (only for training data)
X_train_vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train)

# transform the test data
X_test_vectors = vectorizer.transform(X_test)

# Linear SVM

from sklearn import svm

clf_svm = svm.SVC(kernel="linear")

clf_svm.fit(X_train_vectors, y_train)

clf_svm_pred = clf_svm.predict(X_test_vectors)

# Evaluate Model Accuracy
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

accuracy_score(y_test, clf_svm_pred) 
# Output is .86

# Naive Bayes

from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

clf_gnb = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf_gnb.fit(X_train_vectors, y_train)

clf_gnb_pred = clf_gnb.predict(X_test_vectors)

# Evaluate Model Accuracy
accuracy_score(y_test, clf_gnb_pred)
# Output is .86
```

Here is an example of the X-train:

```
# Review data ouput
print(X_train_vectors.toarray())
print(X_train[0])
print(X_train_vectors[0])
[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 ...
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]
['I started really investing this year and looking for long term holdings After about 5 months or so I have decided to start putting money into ETFs for the time being while I research and learn about companies more For ETFs Im thinking about are the followingVOOQQQIm looking for another ETF that is not apart of Tech to kind of help diversify my holdings I was wondering if XLC would be a good third ETF My plan right now is each month put X amount into a single ETF then the next month put it into the next ETF etc and essentially continously put money into all three ETFs Im in my late 20s and my goal is to hold long term 10  15 years or longer If anyone has suggestions on other ETFs I would greatly appreciate it as Im trying to find the right ETFs to get into and hopefully grow over timeThank you in advance'
 'What 3 ETFs are good to diversify with and buy into']
  (0, 517)  1
  (0, 1007) 1
```

Where y-train for this is 1 (positive).

Here is y_test and the predictions from Kernel SVM:

```
print(y_test)
[ 1  1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1  1  1  1 -1
  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  1 -1  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1  1  1  1 -1  1 -1
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1  1  1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1
  1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1  1  1  1
  1  1]
print(clf_svm_pred)
[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
```

And so on. Same output for decision tree.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Could you provide a few rows of the data (X and y from the test set)

Comment: @MateuszDorobek I just added the output of one of them! I can provide my GitHub which has the submissions.csv since the data is very long for some of them. It's MadisonL19 and it's reddit-ticker-analysis

Comment: The problem is with y, could you put an example of `y_test`, `clf_gnb_pred` and `clf_svm_pred`

Comment: Also what's the size of the (esp. test) dataset?

Comment: @MateuszDorobek Added - also revised a bug in my Naive Bayes. Score for that is .17, and output is all -1. I think I may know what my issue is - data is skewed? Too many positive samples and not enough neutral and negative?

Comment: @BenReiniger about 728 submissions, 80% training 20% testing

Comment: @MadisonLeopold I think you should use `stratify` paramater of `train_test-split`: `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_arr, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0, stratify=y)` Check out the documentation: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Comment: Please revise your title accordingly - you don't seem to talk about same accuracy scores, you seem to  talk about same *predictions*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is the cause of the problem, but since the output of you SVM model and DecisionTreeClassfier always output 1, I suggest you try a more complex model like RandomForestClassifier and see what it comes out.

I've similar experience before, no matter how I tuned the training hyperparameters, the model always give the same performance metric -- this may cause by 2 probabilities:

1. Our data is not suitable for the model, for example all values in the vector is zero: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2. Our model is too simple, which could only perform linear modeling, so that it could not learn too complex mapping function.

Since your SVM is built with linear kernel, could you try an more complex model and see what it comes out? And could you examine that if your X_train_vectors is all zero's in the matrix?

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment! I really appreciate the feedback, guidance, and explanation! I think you're right, the data is pretty complex so I think it's difficult for more similar models to really make any meaning from it. I think the samples I'm feeding are also skewed - too many positives compared to negatives. I'm going to take this feedback and revise - thank you again!!

Comment: You're welcome, or you may try nonlinear kernel for SVM. But for parse data like yours, I suggest neural network.